# Python/Openpyxl repeating data

Tags: python, excel, file, openpyxl

I am creating a program to move all individual quotes into a single quote matrix, using python and openpyxl, but when trying to load the model information it seems to be repeating the models from the first quote. Each quote is a separate excel file, it is confusing me as I'm having no problem getting the quote information, i.e. name, dates, etc. but the list of models is the same for every quote instead of pulling the models from each quote.

Data Structures:

```
class Model:
    SKU = None
    cost = None
    qty = None
    qty_remaining = None

class Quote:
    name = None
    number = None
    start_date = None
    end_date = None

    models = []
```

Function to get data from each quote spreadsheet:

```
def load_quote(filename):
    quote_wb = load_workbook(filename=filename, data_only=True, read_only=True)
    quote_sheet = quote_wb.active


    quote = Quote()

    quote.number = quote_sheet['A2'].value
    quote.number = quote.number[9:len(quote.number)]

    quote.name = quote_sheet['A3'].value
    quote.name = quote.name[14:len(quote.name)]

    quote.start_date = quote_sheet['A6'].value
    quote.start_date = quote.start_date[14:len(quote.start_date)]

    quote.end_date = quote_sheet['A7'].value
    quote.end_date = quote.end_date[12:len(quote.end_date)]


    for row_vals in quote_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=12, max_row=250, min_col=1, max_col=9, values_only=True):
        model = Model()
        if row_vals[0] is not None:
            model.SKU = row_vals[0]
            model.cost = row_vals[4]
            model.qty = row_vals[6]
            model.qty_remaining = row_vals[8]
            quote.models.append(model)
        else:
            continue
        
    return quote
```

Each quote is formatted the same, with the quote number being in cell A2, name being in cell A3, start date in cell A4, and end date in cell 5.

From row 12 to 250 is each model in this format:

| SKU | Description | Cost | Original Quantity | Quantity Used | Quantity Remaining |

I do not need the Description or Quantity Used, so I ignore those. If the quote_sheet variable changes based on iterating through each file in a folder, and it is getting all the quote information from each file, why is it not getting the model information from each file?

Not sure if the function call is helpful but here that is as well:

```
quotes = []
for file in os.listdir(os.chdir(directory)):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        quote = load_quote(file)
        quotes.append(quote)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All attributes of `Quote` and `Model` are defined on the class level - they are **class attributes**. Class attributes are shared across all instances of a class.

This is not a problem for immutable data like `int` or `str`, because by writing:

```
q1 = Quote()
q1.name = 'quote_name'
```

you essentially create a new **instance attribute** `name` bound to the instance `q1` at runtime, which allows the instance to avoid looking up the `Quote.name` class attribute when you ask for its name.

However, since `Quote.models` is a **mutable data** (list), it is shared across all instances of `Quote`. If you append to that list, this in-place operation will be reflected across any instance of that class.

You can see this behavior with this short example:

```
class Quote:
    name = None
    number = None
    start_date = None
    end_date = None

    models = []

q1 = Quote()
q2 = Quote()
q1.models.append('x')
print(q2.models)  # output: ['x']
```

The easiest way to fix this is to turn `Quote.models` into a proper instance attribute, by defining it in the `__init__` method. This way, each `Quote` instance is created with an unique, independent list attached to its `models` attribute:

```
class Quote:
    name = None
    number = None
    start_date = None
    end_date = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.models = []
```

This should be enough to fix your issue, although I'd really recommend turning all class attributes from `Quote` and `Model` into proper instance attributes - for the sake of clarity.

Comment: So __init__(self): is how to write constructors in python? I am going through my CS degree and have only worked in Java so far but figured writing this program would be better than doing it by hand for work, and python seemed to have the easiest excel library. In this case should all the variables be under the constructor since they are attributes of each individual object?

EDIT: Just reread and saw you answered this in your last sentence, thank you

Comment: @WillScott yes, the `__init__` method is commonly thought as the "constructor" in Python. Any attribute bound to the `self` argument (i.e. the instance being constructed) will be set on an instance of the class, once created.

Comment: You should think of class attributes as "data that all instances of a class have access to". A significant differente between Python and Java is that, in Python, attributes can be set at runtime - which is what you inadvertedly did by writing `q1 = Quote(); q1.name = 'foo'`.

Comment: Python's handling of class attributes is one of the few areas where the difference between mutable and immutable types routinely causes problems.